# load ajax content before showing tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-tools, jquery-tooltip

- I wanted to create a drop down at a
  certain position based on a users
  click and
- I wanted this to come  in the form of a drop down also
- the content in the drop down would be dynamically genereated through
  ajax..
- im using jquery-tools tooltip to do this but am facing some problem...
- the ajax content is loading only after the second click ..

THIS IS THE CODE TO CREATE AN ARRAY of TOOLTIP OBJECTS

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var show = false;
         var tips = new Array();
             $(".replie").each(function(){
                $(this).tooltip({ effect: 'fade', events:  {widget:'click,'},position:"bottom right",onBeforeShow:function() {
                    this.getTrigger().fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
                    }})
                tips.push($(this).tooltip(0));
                });
```

AND THIS IS THE CODE TO CONTROL THE TOOLTIPS BEHAVIOR AND LOAD AJAX CONTENT

```
    $(".replie").click(function(evt){
        if(!evt){
                    evt=window.event;
                }
            var row =evt.target.parentNode.id[2];
            var aid=evt.target.id;
            var uid= <?php echo $uid ?>;
            var tip;
            $("#tip"+row).load("reply.php?uid="+uid+"&aid="+aid,function(){
                $(this).hide()
            });

            if(tips[row].isShown)
            {
                tips[row].hide();
            }
            else
            {
                tips[row].show();
            }

        });
```

**HOW DO I LOAD THE CONTENT AND THEN SHOW THE TOOLTIP .. ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jQuery.ajax()` function instead of `jQuery.load()` function. You can set a callback function on `complete` or `success` event. Inside that handler, trigger the tooltip function.

This is the documentation of `jQuery.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/